# Why Modules are not showing in app module dependency

Tags: android, android-module

> I am trying to add module in my main app but its not showing in select
>   section.I am using android studio 3.4.1

**Android Root Directory**

[image: Android Root]

**gradle setting**

[image: gradle setting]

**Module dependency**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I was getting the same issue with Android Studio 3.6.3. The main issue is that the module you imported is registered as an "application" and not as a "library". And it seems only libraries can be imported. Here is what I did to resolve it.

Following the android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library):

1. Open your module's (openCVLibrary441 in your case) build.gradle
2. Change `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` at the top of your file.
3. Delete the line `applicationId` in the `defaultConfig {}` as only an Android app module can define this.
4. Now you should be able to see the module in the module dependency option. Optionally, you can add it manually in you app's build.gradle by adding `implementation project(':openCVLibrary441')` in the `dependencies {}` section.
5. Sync your gradle files and you should be ready to go.